# Seeking tutorial on Time Slider in Carto?

Tags: carto, references, gui

I want to add a time slider to a map. It looks as if I have to do that via CartoCSS but I really don't know where to start. Unfortunately, I don't understand what all the other posts regarding this issue say.

**Does anyone know of a super basic tutorial on how to add a slider to a map?**

Comment: Are you using BUILDER, CARTO.JS or CARTO VL?

Answer (score 0):

The best tutorial about **how to animate a point dataset in CARTO BUILDER** is [this guide](https://carto.com/learn/guides/styling/animating-maps-with-point-data/). Bear in mind that Torque, the client-side Javascript library that BUILDER uses to aggregate and animate data temporarily, has some limitations:

- Only point data is supported. If you have lines or polygons, you will need to convert them using something like `ST_Centroid` or  `ST_PointOnSurface`, or a couple of BUILDER analysis such as selecting points in polygons or creating centroids from geometries.
- Your dataset needs to have a date field. Numeric fields also work but selecting this type of column will not aggregate your data in temporal buckets such as months, days, years and so on. You can transform string/numeric fields into dates using `to_timestamp` function.
- Only one Torque layer (heatmap, animated...) can be shown in a BUILDER map.

If your dataset already covers these points, as explained in the guide, you basically need to:

1. Select your layer.
2. Select `ANIMATED` in the aggregation carousel at the top of the `STYLE` tab.
3. Select your date field.

After the 2nd point, BUILDER will automatically style your layer as animated and add a time series widget (aka time slider) to your map.